# Counts Posts ( custom post type ) by Author in author.php

Tags: custom-post-types

Here is the code that I use to counts posts for one post_type, I would like to use multiple post_type ( post_type_1, post_type_2... ) anyone can help me doing this ?

Thanks for the help.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = '" . $curauth->ID . "' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");
?>

<h2>Post Count: <?php echo $post_count; ?></h2>
```

Comment: [`count_user_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so there are some problems with your code...

1. Your SQL isn't very safe. It would be much nicer, if you used prepare method:

   ```
   $wpdb->get_var(
       $wpdb->prepare(
           "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_author = %d AND post_type = %s AND post_status = %s",
           $curauth->ID, 'post', 'publish'
       )
   );
   ```
2. You clearly say, that you want to count only posts `post_type = 'post'` is the part that is responsible for that. So just remove that part or modify it according to your needs.
3. Be careful counting different post types - remember that attachment (and so on) is also a post type.
4. Use built in functions. It would be much nicer to use [`count_user_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts).

   ```
   <?php $curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); ?>
   <h2>Post Count: <?php echo count_user_posts( $curauth->ID, 'post_type' ); ?></h2>
   ```